# PowerShell command to filter records with multiple values

Tags: powershell

I am working with PowerShell commands. I want to filter records with one field name description. I successfully filter with one description named "school". 
My command is:

```
Get-ADuser -filter {(Description -eq "school")} -Properties * | select *
```

But I want to filter records with multiple values of description like "school", "college", etc. How will this be possible?

Answer (score 10):

You could use an `-or` statement:

```
Get-ADuser -filter {(Description -eq "school") -or (Description -eq "college")} -Properties * | select *
```

Or you could create an array and filter the results, although this is filtering after the query executes, so it may take longer. It would make sense to try and apply a filter to Get-AdUser before passing it through `where-object`:

```
@filter = @("school", "college")
Get-ADuser -Properties * | where-object{@filter -contains $_.Description} | select *
```

Comment: If your question has been answered, please [mark the answer that you feel best addressed your question as accepted](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers), rather than posting a comment thanking the answerer. Once you have at least 15 rep, you can also [upvote](http://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote) the accepted answer and any other answers you found useful.

Comment: The second approach violates the principle of "filter left, format right" -- it brings back lots of records from AD, and then filters them locally. I like the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48913553/1238406) from @TNT for that reason.

Answer (score 5):

David Martin's approach is a bit static. If we want to search for a varying number of descriptions we need to do something like:

```
$descriptions = "school", "college"
$filter = ($descriptions | % { "Description -eq '$_'" }) -join ' -or '
Get-ADuser -filter $filter -Properties Description
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
get-aduser -filter * -properties *|? {$_.description -like "school" -or $_.description -like "college"}
```

If you want to search for descriptions that contain school, add `"*school*"` and it'll look for any instance of school in the description.